# YCbCr 4:2:0 4K 60Hz Output over HDMI 1.4 on Intel Integrated Graphics

Tags: intel-graphics, xrandr, 4k-monitor

I want to display 4K/60Hz screen over HDMI 1.4, mapped to Intel UHD 630. Currently I don't know how to change YCbCr color space format of display output, nor whether this is supported on Intel UHD 630. There's so little documents on the webs...

If you don't know what I want to achieve, you can read [this](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/nvidia-kepler-4k-hdmi-1.4,27117.html)(about Nvidia's implementation).